# How to use `get_loc` to find index of multiple columns within MultiIndex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following spreadsheet:

[image]

which has a two header MultiIndex retrieved with:

```
df = pd.read_excel('myspreadsheet.xlsx', header=[0,1])
```

and would like to get the index of every `'Time'` column **without explicitly writing the `'Stage #'`.**

However, doing this does not work with a MultiIndex:

```
df.columns.get_loc('Time')
```

I'm looking for output like `[1,4,7]` or `[0,3,6]` (or the like) to represent the column positions of 'Time'. I suppose something like `[('Stage 1', 0), ('Stage 2', 3), ('Stage 3', 6)]` would also be fine. My end goal is to insert 10 identical columns (from another df) after each `'Time'` column.

How can this be done?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @jezrael updated the question with your very reasonable request  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) with columns with `Time` by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
a = list(df.columns.get_indexer(df.xs('Time', drop_level=False, axis=1, level=1).columns))
print (a)
[0, 3, 6]
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.xs('Time', drop_level=False, axis=1, level=1))
      Stage 1 Stage 2 Stage 3
         Time    Time    Time
ID                           
83823    1400    1100     900
92833    1200    1300    1100
91834     800    2000    1200
61534     600    2200    1300
14151     500    1800    1400
15715     100    1500    1900
91617     200    1300    2100
37245     300    1100    2200
```

For list of tuples:

```
c = df.xs('Time', drop_level=False, axis=1, level=1).columns
b = list(zip(c.get_level_values(0), df.columns.get_indexer(c)))
print (b)
[('Stage 1', 0), ('Stage 2', 3), ('Stage 3', 6)]
```

EDIT:

For new columns need some maths:

```
c = df.xs('Time', drop_level=False, axis=1, level=1).columns
indices_list = list(zip(c.get_level_values(0), df.columns.get_indexer(c)))
print (indices_list)
[('Stage 1', 0), ('Stage 2', 3), ('Stage 3', 6)]

lenlevel1 = len(c.levels[1])
for j, (s, i) in enumerate(indices_list):  
    df.insert(int(i)+(j * 3)+lenlevel1, (s, 'Depth'), 10)
    df.insert(int(i)+(j * 3)+lenlevel1+1, (s, 'Volume'), 20)
    df.insert(int(i)+(j * 3)+lenlevel1+2, (s, 'Radius'), 30)
```

---

```
print (df)
      Stage 1                                   Stage 2                      \
         Time Duration Mode Depth Volume Radius    Time Duration Mode Depth   
ID                                                                            
83823    1400       30    D    10     20     30    1100       30    B    10   
92833    1200       30    E    10     20     30    1300       30    D    10   
91834     800       30    B    10     20     30    2000       30    E    10   
61534     600       30    B    10     20     30    2200       30    E    10   
14151     500       30    B    10     20     30    1800       30    B    10   
15715     100       30    E    10     20     30    1500       30    E    10   
91617     200       30    E    10     20     30    1300       30    D    10   
37245     300       30    D    10     20     30    1100       30    D    10   

                    Stage 3                                    
      Volume Radius    Time Duration Mode Depth Volume Radius  
ID                                                             
83823     20     30     900       30    E    10     20     30  
92833     20     30    1100       30    B    10     20     30  
91834     20     30    1200       30    D    10     20     30  
61534     20     30    1300       30    E    10     20     30  
14151     20     30    1400       30    B    10     20     30  
15715     20     30    1900       30    E    10     20     30  
91617     20     30    2100       30    D    10     20     30  
37245     20     30    2200       30    E    10     20     30
```

Comment: This looks quite perfect, thank you! Just wondering if you think this approach for getting the column indexes for where to insert the 10 new columns (as described in my question's edit) is reasonable?

Comment: Something along the lines of `for i in indices_list:  df.insert(i, ['Depth', 'Volume', 'Radius', …])` where `Depth`, `Volume`, `Radius`, etc. are the names of the new columns.

Comment: Thank you for the insertion code! Turned out more complicated than I was expecting but will try and decipher it. Thank you again jezrael —wish I could give you even more upvotes, you'd deserve them!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', header=[0],skiprows=[0])
```

dataframe;

```
    id  Time    duration
0   1   234 65
1   2   546 779
2   3   353 567
3   4   456 865
```

output;

```
df.Time

0    234
1    546
2    353
3    456
```

Comment: I didn't see the output. Before he edited the question, ı have written my answer. You are right.